# convert fbx to scn programmatically

Tags: xcode9, arkit, fbx

I need to convert a couple of models from fbx to scn/dae is there a way to do it via a script or a framework meant for swift? I have tried Assimpkit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What ultimately worked was to convert fbx to dae using maya and then ran these daes through an xcode script to convert them into "optimized daes"

https://the-nerd.be/2014/11/07/dynamically-load-collada-files-in-scenekit-at-runtime/

this is the article I ended up following.